# Uploading a file and json request together

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

i am doing an angular 4 project and i am in a situation where i have to upload a file to the server. As of now i am doing

```
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.files[0], this.files[0].name);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.delete('Content-Type');
    this.httpClient.post('url', formData, {headers: headers}).subscribe();
```

This works fine , but my question is, i want to send a stringified json as well with the request which has the mapping for my files. How should i go about attaching the file as well as the stringified json. I tried

```
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.files[0], this.files[0].name);
    formData.append('something', '{"vik":"maiya"}');
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.delete('Content-Type');
    this.httpClient.post('url', formData, {headers: headers}).subscribe();
```

which created the request payload as

```
------WebKitFormBoundarysJdQ94YacVJ9jwwP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="NUM.json"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundarysJdQ94YacVJ9jwwP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="something"

{"vik":"maiya"}
------WebKitFormBoundarysJdQ94YacVJ9jwwP--
```

Is this the right way to do it ? Will the server be able to parse the different parts of the request ? If not how it should be ideally ? Please help. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I have recently try to send json stringify object and images with multipart header, but server is not able to read data because now it's not a content-type JSON header.

If any one have good work around I would like to study scenario.

Solution: send string with formdata append property and server can read able to data.